# Implement deterministic authenticated encryption using libsodium

Tags: symmetric, nonce, chacha, libsodium, poly1305

*Note: this is my first question on stack exchange, let me know if you miss some details to answer and I will edit the question accordingly*

## Context

I'm  willing to create a git encryption tool (`marauder`) that will encrypt files that are marked in `.gitattributes`.

`.gitattributes`

```
my-project.password filter="marauder" diff="marauder" merge=marauder"
.env filter="marauder" diff="marauder" merge=marauder"
```

`.git/config`

```
[filter "marauder"]
  clean = ~/marauder git-clean
  smudge = ~/marauder git-smudge
[diff "marauder"]
  textconv = ~/marauder git-diff
  cachetextconv = true
[marauder]
  key = d2rmvoMBcPAcs-otYtbRH_WIIztXtg7ONcbGgzwcpQo=
```

This, with above config will encrypt files before sending them to the server, and decrypt them on `git pull`.

## Key characteristics

- **Authenticated encryption** (AEAD): we are using https://github.com/elasticdog/transcrypt but it does not offer authentication. We had a bug were the key wasn't set correctly (env variable not set) and the decryption run unsuccessfully with a key "undefined", making the clear text completely wrong. We would prefer to have the CI process failing
- **Deterministic**: as the file is encrypted in git, we cannot afford to have the blob changing every time, even if the text stay the same. That means for symmetric encryption "stable nonce"
- **State of the art crypto**: a good balance between "boring" (not too recent, established) and "feature proof"

## Library

OpenSSL, especially on older mac doesn't include AEAD scheme, such as AES-GCM.

I have planed this to rely on libsodium secret box (xsalsa20 and poly1305).

## Question

> What will be the best way to do a proper AEAD scheme, with deterministic encryption using libsodium

## Prior research & proposed solutions

### Solution 1: Deterministic nonce based on content

pseudo code

```
// Given
let key = <32 bits random key>
// Then
let nonce = crypto_generichash_blake2b(file_content, key)[:24]
let authenticatedciphertext = crypto_secretbox(file_content, nonce, key)
```

**Pro**:

- simple
- "looks" (ugg) correct

**Cons**:

- not standard
- is it safe to use blacke2b hash to generate nonce?

### Solution 2: Daence

https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/067.pdf

**Pro**:

- at least some crypto analysis

**Cons**:

- libsodium wrapper (eg node) doesn't expose HSalsa20
- is there any review on the above paper

### Solution 3: XChaCha20-HMAC-SHA256-SIV

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-madden-generalised-siv-00

**Pro**:

- at least some crypto analysis

**Cons**:

- draft
- I haven't tested implementing it

## Final words

I lack cryptographic knowledge saying what is better, and why.

Considering the above context (medium size message, relative short number of message, deterministic nonce), what will you do and why ?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-xchacha20-siv - It does exactly what you are looking for.